# iOS: Adding a third label to UITableViewCell without creating a Custom cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I've worked with custom cells before but I just wondered for adding a third label (nothing else!) is there a simpler solution? All I want to do is show the title, content and date. I've set the first two to the textLabels and detailTextLabels but I of course need a third for date.

So, is there a simpler solution without making a custom cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [A Closer Look at Table-View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1), section called Programmatically Adding Subviews to a Cell’s Content View.

```
mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 220.0, 15.0)] autorelease];
mainLabel.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
mainLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the tag? I had to omit it in my initial implementation but now what happens is if I make two searches whenever I tap on a result of the second search the value of the result in the same row from the previous search overlaps it. Wondering if that's because I left the tag out.

Comment: When the data source creates your cells, it assigns each a tag. A tag is an identifier of a view; it allows you to locate a view in its view hierarchy by calling the viewWithTag: method.

Comment: Thanks Jon. As you're more familiar with the term do you think it'd have anything to do with my issue? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining what is happening as I've never implemented a search on a uitableview. My practical understanding of the `UITableViewCell.tag` property is simply use it for efficiency reasons whenever you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting into cellForRowAtIndexPath (each time you create a new cell) modifying the textLabel and detailTextLabel Frame and adding to cell.contentView a new Label for the date...
But i think the correct way is to subclass the UItableViewCell class and create a custom cell